# Select not loading options from collection, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to load a simple select drop down menu from a collection. This is my code:

```
 select("campus", "name", Campus.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.lat + "," + r.lng ] },  {:prompt => 'Select Campus'}, {:onchange => 'campus_change(this)'})
```

in my localhost (using SQLlite) it works fine, but in my production server (MYSQL) it is not loading the options.
I have checked the database and the table *has* the information I need to load, so that is not the problem.

Edit:
It seems that there are 2 databases. The results I am displaying for one table are not the same that are displayed in rails console. I don't know how two switch between them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seeds were populating the wrong database.

To populate the production db I had to run:

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production
```

That fixed the problem